ASP.NET Core 6 : The best way to list a group of numbers in a string?
I have a string of numbers in the form of an object like this :
{ "7": "14", "8": "16", "10": "18", "19": "20" }

I want to put the numbers before ":" in a list and the numbers after it in a list, what is the best way to do this?

Can you provide the expected result?

What do you mean by "in the form of an object"?

So basically you want a list of keys and a list of values from the JSON object?

@MatthewWatson like object values

@juunas yes exactly

And "object values" mean what?

So the end result should look like list1 = ["7", "8", "10", "19"], list2 = ["14",  "16", "18", "20"]?

@ZoharPeled yes but just numbers

Working with Newtonsoft.Json, you can convert it to JObject and extract the keys and values via Properties() an Values().
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Linq;

JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(input);
var keys = jObj.Properties()
    .Select(x => x.Name)
    .Where(x => int.TryParse(x, out _))
    .ToList();
var values = jObj.Values()
    .Select(x => x.ToString())
    .Where(x => int.TryParse(x, out _))
    .ToList();

From the Dictionary<string, string> instance, you can work with System.Linq to extract the Key and Value.
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

var dict = /* Dictionary<string, string> instance */;
        
var keys = dict.Select(x => x.Key)
    .Where(x => int.TryParse(x, out _))
    .ToList();
var values = dict.Select(x => x.Value)
    .Where(x => int.TryParse(x, out _))
    .ToList();


Note: this only works if the keys are unique.
You could deserialize the JSON object into a dictionary and get the values from there:
var dict = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>("{\"1\":\"2\",\"3\":\"4\"}");
// Lists available in:
// dict.Keys
// dict.Values
// if you need them as numbers, you could do something like this:
// dict.Keys.Select(v => int.Parse(v))

This is using the newer System.Text.Json library but JSON.NET would also work.

We haven't found out yet if the OPs "Keys" are unique.

Ooh, yeah this won't work in that case if they are not.

try this out.
// JSON input
string jsonInput = "{\"7\":\"14\",\"8\":\"16\",\"10\":\"18\",\"19\":\"20\"}";

// Deserialize the JSON into a dictionary
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(jsonInput);

// Combine key-value pairs into "key:value" format
var combinedDict = dict.Select(kvp => $"{kvp.Key}:{kvp.Value}").ToList();

// Serialize the combined list back to JSON format
string jsonOutput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(combinedDict);

// Output the result
Console.WriteLine(jsonOutput);

It will give you output like
["7:14","8:16","10:18","19:20"]


provided that the values are always not empty. otherwise, you will need to add a length check so as not to crash from the index.
string test = @"{ ""7"": ""14"", ""8"": ""16"", ""10"": ""18"", ""19"": ""20"" }";

test = test
    .Replace("{", "")
    .Replace(" ", "");
string[] strs = test.Split(',');
IList<int> keys = new List<int>();
IList<int> values = new List<int>();
foreach (string str in strs) {
    string[] pair = str.Split(':');
    keys.Add(int.Parse(pair[0]));
    values.Add(int.Parse(pair[1]));
}

